# VBA copy range from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I know this is probably very ametuer stuff. I've been trying to teach myself VBA for a project I am working on and could use a little guidance. Will make sure to credit the person with the correct answer.

I currently know basic c++

I am trying to build a Macro that does this:

1. Start at the top of the sheet (A2) - take that value
2. Compare that with the value of the ActiveCell
3. Iterate down the A column and once a unique value is found...
4. Remember that Cell
5. Move over 3 columns
6. Follow a hyperlink to a range in a new sheet
7. Return to the cell in step 4
8. Insert the range copied and shift the rest of the sheet down
9. Repeat down the sheet (I haven't tried to implement this part at all yet)

Here is what I've written so far:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim CellValue As Integer

    Range("A2").Select
    CellValue = Range("A2").Value

    While Selection.Value <> ActiveCell.Value
    ' If CellValue = ActiveCell.Value Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Wend

    Dim SaveLine As Range
    SaveLine = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell = SaveLine
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

I'm getting two errors:

1. overflow error @ `CellValue = Range("A2).Value`
2. Run-time error '91' - Object variable or With block variable not set @ `SaveLine = ActiveCell`

Any guidance (even partial) is appreciated.

Comment: Right off the top, you'll want to read-up on the `Long` data type, which can handle much larger numbers than `Integer`. Here's an MSDN link on the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y595sc15.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For point 1. [Dan Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3075291/dan-wagner) already replied in comments. For point 2 you might want to write instead:

```
Set SaveLine = ActiveCell
```

By default `X = Y` means `Let X = Y`, which does not apply for Objects in VBA (objects are  being referenced rather than copied after creation).